# How do I change an array such that repeating elements only show up once?

Tags: java, arrays

This is slightly different than just removing duplicates (which you can do using `LinkedHashSet`). If I have an array like this in Java that I got from a `byte[]` array and then converted to a `String` array:

```
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0]
```

Is there a way to change it to something like this:

```
[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0]
```

I've tried using a `HashSet` and a `LinkedHashSet`, but it doesn't do what I want. The different sets of 0's stay even if they are technically duplicates. Thanks so much!

Comment: There isn't a built in data structure that will do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to loop over the elements and copy the non-consecutive duplicating elements to a new collection:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){
         int[] values = {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0};

         List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         if(values.length > 0){
            int previous = values[0];
            output.add(previous);
            for(int value : values){
                if(previous != value){
                    output.add(value);
                }
                previous = value;
            }
         }
         System.out.println(output); // [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! This worked perfectly. As @pwilmot stated, it looks like there isn't a data structure that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the input array and emit just the first value of each sequence. This pseudo-C# algorithm should guide you:

```
int[] a = ... // input array
int[] b = new int[a.Length]; // same size
int i, j;

if (a.Length == 0)
{
    // return a zero-length array
}

i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < a.Length)
{
    b[j] = a[i];
    while(i < a.Length && a[i] == b[j])
    {
        i++;
    }
    j++;
}

// return the sub-array of "b" from "0" to "j - 1"
```

That's all.